# Check if a session id valid by sessionId only in tomcat?

Tags: session, tomcat

How is it possible to check if a tomcat session is valid by knowing only the sessionid?

I want to create a REST endpoint that checks if a session is valid by passing it just the sessionId. The session cookie is not available in this request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HttpServletRequest#isRequestedSessionIdValid` method to check whether the request session is valid or not:

```java
@GET  
public Response someMethod(@Context HttpServletRequest request) { 
  System.out.print(request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()); 
}
```